# How can I show single data per page in react with javascript data file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am developing a health testing app. In that development, I have an issue with showing data. I have a JavaScript data file and inside that I give id for the single question. For example

```
const DATA = [
  {
    id: 1,
    Ques:
      "How much you have been bothered by numbness or tingling during the past month?",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    Ques:
      "How much you have been bothered by feeling hot during the past month?",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    Ques:
      "How much you have been bothered by wobbliness in legs during the past month?",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    Ques:
      "How much you have been bothered by unable to relax during the past month?",
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    Ques:
      "How much you have been bothered by fear of worst happening during the past month?",
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    Ques:
      "How much you have been bothered by dizzy or lightheaded during the past month?",
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    Ques:
      "How much you have been bothered by heart pounding / racing during the past month?",
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    Ques: "How much you have been bothered by unsteady during the past month?",
  },
];
```

With that data, I want to show the first question in first page and there will be check box for that question. When you click check box and click next button, another question will be replace in first question area. How can I create that app with react?

The react code of my development is here and I map those data and that is not the thing that I wanted to do. How can I change the code?

```
import React from "react";

const TestQuestion = (ques) => {
  const { Ques } = ques;
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Test</h1>
      <div>
        <span>{Ques}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TestQuestion;
```

```
class TestPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      testing: DATA,
    };
  }
  render() {
    const { testing } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {testing.map(({ id, ...otherTestingProps }) => (
          <TestQuestion key={id} {...otherTestingProps} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default TestPage;
```

For that code, How can I changed? And in this code the next button and the check box is not include!

Comment: Can you share your React code so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be sure to take the [tour] and read [ask]. One of the important differences between Stack Overflow and a typical forum is the quality of the questions and answers. One way the quality is kept high is by asking posters to research their posts first, and show the results of that research in the post. That way everyone gets the benefit of the prior research, and those who answer can gauge the asker's skill level and adapt their answer accordingly.

Comment: I have updated the question with react code.

Answer (score 1):

you should add an onClick to the next button which does

```
this.props.history.push("url?question="+this.state.question.id+1)
```

and on every page first of all you have to get that url id and render the question with the given id like this:

```
let id = this.props.location.search.split("gold=question=")[1][1]
```

now you can render the question with the given id

you can learn more about what i did by searching about react query parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can define a counter function which increments a counter value each time the next button is clicked and based on the value of counter you display each question from the `testData` file. For example, the counter value is 0 and you display the `testData[0].Question`. And for handling the checkbox, you can make the next button disbaled unless the question is checked. This solution works if you intend to stay same page each time the question changes. In case you want to change the url, you need to use `history.push('/${testData[counter].id}')` when the next button is clicked.